# Parse text with date and timestamp using Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string -

```
Default (45-889) %69 (Test Case)-1/24/2012 12:16:01 AM-1/24/2012 12:16:11 AM-1/24/2012 12:16:24 AM-1/24/2012 12:18:03 AM-1/24/2012 12:19:15 AM-1/24/2012 12:19:52 AM-1/24/2012 12:19:59 AM-1/24/2012 12:20:03 AM
```

I would like to split the above string into an array using Regex in C#.

After split my array should look like :

- `Default (45-889) %69 (Test Case)`
- `1/24/2012 12:16:01 AM`
- `1/24/2012 12:16:11 AM`

How do I use Regex to split the string into array of strings in C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't see why you need regex here; it appears your delimiter is the dash character, so you can use

```
string[] words = s.Split('-');
```

can't you?

Comment: I cannot because I need the complete first part Default (45-889) %69 (Test Case).

Comment: Then use the `Split` command I show above, and rejoin array elements [0] and [1] with a dash.

Comment: Struggling for last few minutes but unable to come up with a good regex expression. As you say, might be easier to split.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to just split on "-".

You'd also need to check that each part has the same number of "(" and ")" because of the first part which has a "-" between "(" and ")".